# Java OutputStream that incrementally processes text

Tags: java, outputstream

I want to incrementally process the text written to an `OutputStream` as it is written.

For example, suppose we have this program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Streaming {

    // Writes file, incrementally, to OutputStream.
    static void dump(File file, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        // Implementation omitted
    }

    static int sum = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Charset charSet = Charset.defaultCharset(); // Interpret the file as having this encoding.
        dump(new File("file.txt"), new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                // Add b to bytes already read,
                // Determine if we have reached the end of the token (using
                //   the default encoding),
                // And parse the token and add it to `sum`
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Suppose `file.txt` is a text file containing a space-delimited list of ints. In this program, I wish to find the sum of the ints in `file.txt`, accumulating the sum in the `sum` variable. I would like to avoid building up a String that is millions of characters long.

I'm interested in a way that I can accomplish this using the `dump` function, which writes the contents of a file to an output stream. I'm *not* interested in reading the file in another way (e.g. creating a `Scanner` for `file.txt` and repeatedly calling `nextInt` on the scanner). I'm imposing this restriction because I'm using a library that has an API similar to `dump`, where the client must provide an `OutputStream`, and the library subsequently writes a lot of text to the output stream.

How can I implement the `write` method to correctly perform the steps as outlined? I would like to avoid doing the tokenization by hand, since utilities like `Scanner` are already capable of doing tokenization, and I want to be able to handle any encoding of text (as specified by `charSet`). However, I can't use `Scanner` directly, because there's no way of checking (in a non-blocking way) if a token is available:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Charset charSet = Charset.defaultCharset();
        PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(in, charSet)) {
            dump(new File("file.txt"), new PipedOutputStream(in) {
                @Override
                public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
                    super.write(b, off, len);
                    // This will loop infinitely, because `hasNextInt`
                    // will block if there is no int token currently available.
                    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                        sum += sc.nextInt();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
        System.out.println(charSet);
    }
```

Is there a non-blocking utility that can perform the tokenization for me as data is written to the output stream?

Comment: "I expect that this will involve writing a new subclass of OutputStream" - I think you have already answered your question. If you are trying to do this and have run into a roadblock, you should clarify that.

Comment: My roadblock is that I don't know how to incrementally parse text when `write` is called. I tried to clarify the last paragraph of the question.

Comment: Let's say that you are receiving one byte at a time. You are going to need to have a little buffer where you are building the next integer. As you receive bytes, you need to create characters. As you complete each character, you need to see if it is part of the partial integer or a space. If it is a space (or close() is called), you will need to parse the integer and do whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: I would like to use something like `Scanner` because it does the tokenization for me, taking into account the charset that I specify. (I would like to avoid manually doing the tokenization.) However, `Scanner` is not good for incremental use. If no input is currently available, its `hasNext` method is blocking, instead of immediately returning that no input is available.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, [FilterOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html) is what you want to subclass.  [DigestOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/DigestOutputStream.html) extends FilterOutputStream and does something somewhat similar to what you want to do:  it monitors the bytes as they come through and passes them to a different class for processing.

One solution that comes to mind is for the FilterOutputStream to pass the bytes to a [PipedOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html), connected to a PipedInputStream which a different thread reads in order to create your sum:

```
PipedOutputStream sumSink = new PipedOutputStream();

Callable<Long> sumCalculator = new Callable<Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long call()
    throws IOException {

        long sum = 0;
        PipedInputStream source = new PipedInputStream(sumSink);

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(source, charSet)) {
            while (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                sum += scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
};
Future<Long> sumTask = ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(sumCalculator);

OutputStream dest = getTrueDestinationOutputStream();
dest = new FilterOutputStream(dest) {
    @Override
    public void write(int b)
    throws IOException {
        super.write(b);
        sumSink.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b)
    throws IOException {
        super.write(b);
        sumSink.write(b);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b,
                      int offset,
                      int len)
    throws IOException {
        super.write(b, offset, len);
        sumSink.write(b, offset, len);
    }

    @Override
    public void flush()
    throws IOException {
        super.flush();
        sumSink.flush();
    }

    @Override
    public void close()
    throws IOException {
        super.close();
        sumSink.close();
    }
};

dump(file, dest);

long sum = sumTask.get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Using the PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream with Scanner is a good idea, but I am hoping for a way to do this in a single thread. It seems possible, since all I need to do is check if the bytes written so far form a complete token.

Answer (score 0):

As "idiomatic" approach, you might want a [`FilterOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html):

> These streams sit on top of an already existing output stream (the underlying output stream) which it uses as its basic sink of data, but possibly transforming the data along the way or providing additional functionality.

At least to me, it sounds something like what you describe.

It is a concrete class <strike>(unlike `OutputStream`)</strike>, so the absolute minimum you can get away with is to provide your constructor and an implementation for the single-byte `write()` (which is going to be invoked by the default implementations of other `write()` methods):

```
public class SumOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
  public int sum = 0;
  public SumOutputStream(OutputStream os) {
    super(os);
  }

  private int num = 0;
  public void write(int b) throws IOException {
    if (b >= '0' && b <= '9') {
      sum -= num;
      num = num * 10 + b - '0';
      sum += num;
    } else {
      num = 0;
    }
    out.write(b);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (SumOutputStream sos = new SumOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("test.txt"))) {
      sos.write("123 456 78".getBytes());
      System.out.println(sos.sum);
      sos.write('9');
      System.out.println(sos.sum);
    }
  }
}
```

This will sum whatever numbers are passing, keeping `sum` up to date all the time even with partial results (that is what separating the `9` is supposed to show).

Comment: Side comment: as you write about handling text, you may rather want to use a [`Writer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html) instead. Should you go for it, [`FilterWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterWriter.html) is at your service in a similar way.

Comment: I don't see a difference between using `FilterOutputStream` and directly writing a subclass of `OutputStream`. (`OutputStream` has a single abstract method, `write`, that I can provide a implementation for. I don't need to forward the written bytes to another output stream, which seems to be the use case for `FilterOutputStream`.) I agree that I would have to "tokenize at line breaks or something like that", but do you know if there is a way to use the Java standard library to do this tokenization for me as the bytes come into the output stream? I don't trust myself to correctly tokenize UTF-8

Comment: @Nick, yes, you are right about `OutputStream`, it has one `abstract void write()` only, the same one. The point of `FilterOutputStream` is that it is intended to pass-through data, so if someone looks at your code, they will know that there is an underlying stream where data (or something derived from it) goes. See the quoted text. `OutputStream` simply does not imply such detail.

Comment: `sum += b - '0'` seems to be generating a sum of the digits encountered, not the sum of space-delimited, possibly multi-digit integer values.

Comment: @VGR yes, that is just a random example (but it is described correctly). Yesterday I simply did not notice the *space-delimited list of ints* part. And now I'm typing on a phone, so the fix has to wait a little.

Comment: @VGR btw, it is done and it ended up being far simpler than what I originally imagined.

Answer (score -1):

Based off @tevemadar's answer. Reads in strings and tries to parse them to ints. If that fails, then you know the number is done and is then added to the sum.  The only problem is that my method doesn't add the last number if it occupies the last two bytes. To solve this, you could add a single line method: `if(!currNumber.isEmpty()) sum += Integer.parseInt(currNumber);` that you can call once the file finishes.

```
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Objects;

class SumOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {
  public int sum = 0;
  String currNumber = "";
  String lastChar = "";

  public SumOutputStream(OutputStream os){
    super(os);
  }

  public void write(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException {
      Objects.checkFromIndexSize(off, len, b.length);
      for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
          try { 
              if(!lastChar.isEmpty()) {
                  Integer.parseInt(lastChar);
                  currNumber += lastChar;
              }
          } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
              if(!currNumber.isEmpty()) sum += Integer.parseInt(currNumber);
              currNumber = "";
          }  catch(NullPointerException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          write(b[off + i]);
          lastChar = new String(b);
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if `dump` splits one entry from the file (e.g. `1234`) across multiple calls to write (e.g. first it calls write for just `12`, and then it calls write for just `34`), then this answer does not do the right thing. We would somehow need to maintain a buffer of all bytes written to the output stream, detect if a full token has been formed, and only then add the number to the "sum." I'm just not sure how to "detect if a full token has been formed".

Comment: @Nick, I have added changes to my answer to account for your example case.